# RAID for load balancer needed?

Tags: load-balancing, raid1

We have two load balancers, one used as hot-standby. Would you recommend me using a RAID1 setup in case of a harddisk failure? Or is RAID1 not needed as in case of a failure the hot-standby server takes over?

Comment: It's Murphy: as long as you have a well-maintained RAID 1, nothing ever happens. Try having a server without any disk redundancy, and it *will* crash and burn at the worst possible moment. (Been there, done that ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use RAID1 in this case (actually, we do have an HPC cluster here with a similar setup: two master servers, one of which serves as standby; both have RAID1 disks). If the machine is important enough for you to pay for an HA pair, the minimal extra costs for RAID1 should not be an obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

If the disks are non-RAIDed and the hot-standby goes active for whatever reason, a simple broken disk on that server will disable your whole setup, making your whole work useless.

In other words: When doing that kind of HA setup, I would consider a RAID essential. It's not that more expensive to justify the added risk (IMHO, of course).